# How to cancel GCD queue through pthread in iOS?

Tags: ios, concurrency

I know GCD doesn't have any built-in support for cancellation, but GCD is builds on libdispatch, I guess GCD may create on pthread, so how to using the pthread that releated to GCD queue to cancel a GCD queue?

Comment: use NSOperation if you really need cancelation

Comment: I heard there have a way to get pthread id and cancel it , but I do not found it in libdispatch